# How to fix the error "You must use withSourcePHIDs() to query edges." when trying to edit my profile in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I successfully setup Phabricator and have been using it for about a week now. I was using it this morning and now I'm suddenly getting the error: "You must use withSourcePHIDs() to query edges." when trying to edit my profile.

I don't see anything wrong with the account and the error is extremely vague. Has anyone else ran into the error? If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this offhand. You should file a bug in the upstream, we'd be happy to look into it. Please include the full stack trace and steps to reproduce.

http://secure.phabricator.com/

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for weighing in. Normally I'd try to be more helpful but there there's no stack trace or any other message than what I listed above. I literally click the button to view my profile and that error message is all I get. 

I worked around it by creating a new account and re-associating it with the projects manually. I'm still trying to figure out how to take over the private projects I setup on my old account.

Comment: Actually...I did do one thing earlier that morning. I changed my name on my profile which was the admin account used to create the instance of phabricator and all the projects/rooms/etc. Maybe that could have something to do with it?

Comment: You should still have a stack trace likely in your php/webserver error log. I can poke around and try to find a repo.